# Equivalence of recursions for A145879

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, sequences-and-series, recurrences

- Let $R_1(n,z)$ be row polynomials of [A145879](https://oeis.org/A145879) i.e. of triangle read by rows: $T(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of $\left\lbrace 1,2,\cdots,n \right\rbrace$ having exactly $k$ entries that are midpoints of $321$ patterns. Here
  $$
  R_1(n,z)=nzR_1(n-1,z)+(1-z)\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}R_1(j-1,z)R_1(n-j,z), \\
  R_1(0,z)=1
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R_2(n,q,z)=(qz+1)R_2(n-1,q+1,z)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}R_2(n-1,j,z), \\
  R_2(0,q,z)=1
  $$

I conjecture that $$R_2(n,0,z)=R_1(n+1,z).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
R1_upto(n)=my(v1); v1=vector(n+1, i, 0); v1[1]=1; for(i=1, n, v1[i+1]=i*z*v1[i]+(1-z)*sum(j=1, i, v1[j]*v1[i-j+1])); v1=vector(n,i,v1[i+1])
R2_upto(n)=my(v1, v2, v3); v1=vector(n+1, i, 1); v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; for(i=1, n, for(q=0, n-i, v2[q+1]=(q*z+1)*v1[q+2] + sum(j=0, q, v1[j+1])); v1=v2; v3[i+1]=v1[1]); v3
test(n)=R1_upto(n)==R2_upto(n-1)
```

Is there a way to prove it?